# Qt: WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated

Tags: mysql, qt4

i using Qt 4.7.3 and mysql 5.5 , i need to build a driver mysql for qt , i see this [link](http://ieatbinary.com/2011/07/11/how-to-enable-mysql-support-in-qt-sdk-for-windows/) and get this error :

```
C:\QtSDK\QtSources\4.7.3\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=%mysql%\include"       "LIBS+=%mysql%\lib\libmysql.lib" -o makefile mysql.pro
WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.
```

what is the problem ??
mysql.pro file [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?m8pnbat42m9t8jt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error, just a warning about a deprecated feature. Try to substitute the `\`   with `/` char. 
Probably the use of `\` as path separator is now deprecated and at some point in the future the warning will become an error.

Comment: same warning , WARNING: (internal):1: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated.

Comment: Can post the .pro file ? Have you substitute all the `\` char ?

Comment: where post .pro file ? i can't understand , i substitute \ by / just ? what about " char ??

Comment: Yes, just all the \ in the paths by /. In your example, it should become `qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=%mysql%/include"       "LIBS+=%mysql%/lib/libmysql.lib" -o makefile mysql.pro` but you need to substitute the \ in all the similar line. Anyway you can just go on also with the warning

Comment: Can you post the mysql.pro file ?

Comment: do you need mysql.pro file ??

Comment: i post it in original question you can see it know

Comment: Probably there is some backslash in one of the .pri file. But as I said, it is just a warning, you can go on without problem